# Графы - дорожная сеть

Tags: графы, c++

Как точно называется задача для покрытия дорожной сетью?

Например есть такой неограф:

[image]

Вес дуг это расстояние между городами.

Применив **минимальное остовное дерево** получается такая картина:
Все вершины связаны в одну большую дорогу, но если перемещаться из Рязани в Казань(по остовному дереву), то потребуется 3+7+7+3=20 шагов.
[image]

То есть данный вид связи подходит для телефонной сети, но не для дорожной.
А в идеале, должна быть еще дорога между Рязанью и Казанью.

[image]

То есть должны быть еще элементы оптимизации, где будет коэфицент зависимость стоимости прокладки дороги по отношению к времени перемещения из городов(как то так).Чем выше такой коэфицент тем больше дуг будет между вершинами.

Есть ли конкретная задача которая этим занимается?

Comment: Задача коммивояжёра. Нет?

Comment: @nicolai, нет. Задача коммивояжера заключается не в построении графа, а в отыскании самого выгодного маршрута на исходном графе, проходящего через все города хотя бы по одному разу и с последующим возвратом в исходный город.

Comment: Хм. Ну это в любом случае задача поиска оптимального подграфа. Если вы сумеете сформулировать условие оптимальности, может быть, это окажется одной из классических задач. (Но я не спец.)

Answer (score 8):

- В первой формулировке (без наложения вспомогательных constraint'ов на стоимость строительства дорог) это — задача нахождения [Shortest total path length spanning tree `[1]`,](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~kmchao/papers/2000_DAM_stsp.pdf) для которой [доказано, что она NP-трудная.](http://www.amazon.com/Computers-Intractability-NP-Completeness-Mathematical-Sciences/dp/0716710455) Решить эту задачу можно с помощью приближенных алгоритмов (см., например, первую ссылку).
- Для такой же задачи, где стоимость постройки дороги не связана с длиной дороги, это будет задача нахождения "**Constrained** shortest total path length spanning tree".

> - Нестрого говоря, эта задача не проще предыдущей, поэтому тоже является NP-трудной. Если формально это доказывать, наверно, нужно сделать такой же переход, как сделали [вот здесь `[2]`](http://math.mit.edu/~goemans/PAPERS/RaviGoemans-1996-TheConstrainedMinimumSpanningTreeProblem.pdf)  при переходе от задачи Minimum Spanning Tree → Constrained Minimum Spanning Tree.
> - Думаю, что для приближенного решения этой задачи можно придумать, как совместить подходы `[1]` и `[2],` если у вас, конечно, много свободного времени `:)`